# SyntaxError if upload file via ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I have a form to upload file via ajax and insert into WordPress as featured image, it always return error

```
Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "<br /><b>"... is not valid JSON
```

If I don't submit it using ajax, there is no error prompt and successfully inserted.

Here is the form and ajax script

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="edit-submit.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="hidden" name="postid" value="30" />
        <input type="input" name="cardid" value="28392148211" readonly />
        <input type="file" name="photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg"  />
        <input id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
    
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'submit.php',
    data : $('#form').serialize(),
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        if (status === 'success') {
            $('#submit').html('Thanks');
            console.log(data);
        }
        console.log(status);
    },
    error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log('Error: ' + errorMessage);
    }
})
```

Here is the PHP submit.php

```
<?php

define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require_once( 'wp-load.php' );

require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );

$post_id = $_REQUEST['postid'];

$attachment_id = media_handle_upload('photo', $post_id);
set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment_id);

$rtn = array('status' => 'success');

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode( $rtn );

?>
```

Comment: Looks like your PHP code is returning some HTML (either instead of, or as well as, the JSON). This often happens if an error occurred in processing the request. Use your browser's Network tool to monitor the AJAX request and then click on the Response tab within that request to view the full output - I'd bet you'll get a clue from that, e.g. an error message, or seeing that there is additional content in the output which shouldn't be there (and thus causes the JSON parsing to fail)

Comment: Anyway the _root_ cause of all that will be because you can't upload a file by serialising a form. That'll only work with text data. So I'd say PHP will be failing because there isn't a file to upload (and possibly the code lacks validation to check for that before attempting to process it).